# Links in mobile menu (<ul> <li a>) doesn't work when used 'touchend' instead of 'click' event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, safari, click

I am new to this field. I have designed a simple website and used javascript to toggle between classes to show and hide menu on mobile view. But, there were some issues. The first problem was that the hamburger button doesn't respond when the website is opened in Safari browser or iPhone, iPad,etc. Then after some research, I found out that if I replace 'click' in addListener with 'touchend', it could work. I did it and yes, the menu is opening and closing as intended, but the links inside are not working. The menu is a simple  Home kind of thing. Please help me. This is really important because the website is currently up and is not getting any traffic from potential customers.

Class "burger" is the burger menu. div "l1" is the menu image.

```
CSS:
#l1{
top: 0; 
width: 40px;
height: 5px;
background-color:#018392;
text-align: center;
margin: 8px;
}

HTML
<div id="burger" class="burger">
     <div id="l1"></div>
</div>
<nav>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="#g">GALLERY</a></li>
     <li><a href="#abt-us">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

JAVASCRIPT
<script>
         window.addEventListener('touchend',function(event){
             var bur=document.getElementById("burger");
             var menu=document.querySelector('ul');
             var l1=document.getElementById("l1");
                 if((event.target==bur)||(event.target==l1)){
                     menu.classList.toggle("active");
                 }                
                 else {
                     menu.classList.remove("active");
                 }
                 
         });
 </script>
```

Comment: "the menu is opening and closing as intended, but the links inside are not working" <= please make an [mcve] of this issue so we can help you debug it

Comment: There’s an extra brace before `else`, delete it.

Comment: @PineCode did that. didn't help though.

Comment: @Taplar is this code okay? As I said, I am new here. That's why I am asking too many questions.

Comment: You need to provide the HTML and CSS code, too.

Comment: I have given the html already. css is #l1{ top: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#018392;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 8px;}

Comment: What you provided was just the JavaScript code, not the HTML code.

Comment: @PineCode oh I see that now. The html I had given has transformed into the design view. The "HOME" "GALLERY" and "ABOUT" were actually posted as html. What do I do now? <div id="burger" class="burger">
                <div id="l1"></div>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#g">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#abt-us">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

Comment: Hi, you don't have any elements with id="li" - and remember you can only have one element with a given id, they must be unique.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
improve text arragement, improve code formatting,
 provide more information about the problem: 
results, screenshots
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Comment: @AHaworth he only uses `l1`, not `li`.

Comment: @AHaworth Hi! It is "l1". it is the id given to line in the burger menu. <div id="burger" class="burger">
                <div id="l1"></div>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#g">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#abt-us">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't see the full HTML.

Comment: @Gander Did as you asked. I had to read a little before I could properly do it. Sorry for the trouble. So, do you see anything wrong in the code now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Safari Mobile 7.0+ (and likely earlier versions too) suffers from a bug where click events aren't fired on elements that aren't typically interactive (e.g. ) and which also don't have event listeners directly attached to the elements themselves" See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#Safari_Mobile

Hence replace your `<div id="burger" class="burger">` with an interactive element e.g. `<button id="burger" class="burger"></button>`